# Installing required packages error while rvm requirements

Tags: rvm, requirements

I am installing `ruby on rails` in `Ubuntu 14.04 using RVM.`

Installed RVM successfully but when try to RUN command rvm requirements then got below error

```
> rvm requirements

Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Installing requirements for ubuntu.
Updating system............
Installing required packages: gawk, libreadline6-dev, zlib1g-dev, libssl-dev, libyaml-dev, libsqlite3-dev, sqlite3, autoconf, libgmp-dev, libgdbm-dev, libncurses5-dev, automake, libtool, bison, libffi-dev.....
Error running 'requirements_debian_libs_install gawk libreadline6-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 autoconf libgmp-dev libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison libffi-dev',
showing last 15 lines of /home/mb-pc/.rvm/log/1463399688/package_install_gawk_libreadline6-dev_zlib1g-dev_libssl-dev_libyaml-dev_libsqlite3-dev_sqlite3_autoconf_libgmp-dev_libgdbm-dev_libncurses5-dev_automake_libtool_bison_libffi-dev.log
 libffi-dev : Depends: libffi6 (= 3.0.11~rc1-5) but 3.1-2 is to be installed
 libgdbm-dev : Depends: libgdbm3 (= 1.8.3-10) but 1.8.3-13 is to be installed
 libgmp-dev : Depends: libgmp10 (= 2:5.0.2+dfsg-2ubuntu1) but 2:6.0.0+dfsg-4build1 is to be installed
 libncurses5-dev : Depends: libncurses5 (= 5.9-4) but 5.9+20140712-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
                   Depends: libtinfo-dev (= 5.9-4) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: ncurses-bin (= 5.9-4)
 libreadline6-dev : Depends: libreadline6 (= 6.2-8) but 6.3-8ubuntu1 is to be installed
                    Depends: libtinfo-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libsqlite3-dev : Depends: libsqlite3-0 (= 3.7.9-2ubuntu1.2) but 3.8.6-1 is to be installed
 libssl-dev : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (= 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.36) but 1.0.1f-1ubuntu9 is to be installed
 sqlite3 : Depends: libsqlite3-0 (= 3.7.9-2ubuntu1.2) but 3.8.6-1 is to be installed
 zlib1g-dev : Depends: zlib1g (= 1:1.2.3.4.dfsg-3ubuntu4) but 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
+ return 100
+ return 100
Requirements installation failed with status: 100
```

I tried to find but not get proper solutions.

Any one have a idea in it.

Thanks

Comment: Try `rvm install 2.3.1`. Does it break?

Comment: Tried it. Same error.